# meteorjs parties example modals on bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, meteor, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm playing a bit with [Parties](https://www.meteor.com/examples/parties) and the thing is I can't get "create party" and "invite" modals to work on bootstrap-3.

The mask (light gray background that hover the page) get launched but no modals appears.

I used: `mrt add bootstrap-3` to add bootstrap (and deleted the default bootstrap version)

Comment: Generally speaking you will have a lot of problems with using `bootstrap-3` modals within `Meteor` in the form they're provided. Most of people I know implements modals themselves instead of fighting with `bootstrap` :)

Comment: It has to work. Maybe you can give us a minimal example? Take care not to include any bootstrap-js file twice or to include jquery.

Comment: @chaosbohne that would give a JS error or something like that, But it just doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got it, I added `show` class to the `div` and it works

```
<div class="modal show">
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to also check out the https://github.com/TimHeckel/meteor-bootboxjs package which (as of now) uses Bootbox 4.2.0 with Bootstrap 3.

It's not Meteor-esque, but it is a nice package for displaying modals that is extensively tested, and you can also insert reactive content into it (if not using the default `alert`, `confirm`, or `prompt`) by using a bit of a hack:

```
var fooDialog = bootbox.dialog(message: " ").html('');
UI.insert(UI.render(Template.bar), fooDialog[0]);
```

Comment: I've tried it and loved it, but I need something I can hack to the fullest since i'm developping for mobile. thx !

Comment: @Alucard why not just render your own modals using templates then?